# get object from [myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] instead of NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i have a custom class called `contact`. This class has attributes like `name, address` etc.
I wish to create an array of type `contact` and display the value of each attibute in a custom cell in UItableview. 
Code to store the data in array:

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            myContact.nm = aName;
            NSString *aAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            myContact.address = aAddress;

            NSLog(@"%@",aName);     
            [list.details addObject:myContact];
            NSLog(@"%@", list.details);

}
```

here details is an array declared as `@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *details;` in .h

My question is that how do i retrieve the values on each index like :

```
[0]->name
[0]->address

[1]->name
[1]->address ....
```

my code in tableview.m:

```
cell.name.text = [details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // not working
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: Have you tried  [details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` returns the `Contact` object. What you need is, `nm` property of `Contact` object which represents the name in your code.

Try this,

```
Contact *myContacts = [details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
cell.name.text = [myContacts nm]; //or [[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nm];
```

Similarly you can get `[myContacts address]` as well.

**Edit:**
Based on your question in comments, the answer is:

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        Contact *myContact = [[Contact alloc] init]; //you should add this here, not outside the loop
        // Read the data from the result row
        NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
        myContact.nm = aName;
        NSString *aAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
        myContact.address = aAddress;

        NSLog(@"%@",aName);
        [list.details addObject:myContact];
        NSLog(@"%@", list.details);

    }
```

Comment: i tried it. My actual databse contains 3 records- abc, xyz, ee but in tableview only the last record is displayed 3 times i.e ee,ee,ee

Comment: Check my answer now. You should add `Contact *myContact = [[Contact alloc] init];` inside the while loop.

Comment: actually i initialized the contact object before while loop! It works now, thanks mate !

Answer (score 1):

First make an object of class.

```
Contact *con = [details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It will store all array in 'con' object.

Then, Use it by,

```
NSLog("Name :: %@", con.nm);
NSLog("Addr :: %@", con.address);
```

It'll refer Name & Address of that particular contact object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nm];
```

In `nm` you just need to input your object. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you looking for

```
cell.name.text = [[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
```

?

Comment: i tried this but i get SIGABRT exception. Stack trace: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[contact name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e00bf0'

Comment: @z22 then your `contact` class doesn't have a property called `name` - **despite you having stated it in the question.** Don't blame your own error on me (time to read an Objective-C tutorial **attentively**...)

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
cell.name.text = [[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nm];
```

When you use this line:

```
[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It returns a object of type `contact`. Then you need to get the `nm` property which stores the name.
So you need to use like:

```
[[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nm];
```